# Sync API table to SQL Database

Tags: database, azure, integration, azure-logic-apps, erp

I'm exploring options on how to one-way sync from a table available via API to an SQL database. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to achieve this?

The data from the "Source" is often updated and should be copied to the "Destination" *as the changes happen (live)*.

**Source**
Read Only table from an ERP available via an API. Webhooks on the source are not possible. Entries to this table may be created, updated or deleted. There would be approximately 150,000 entries in the table with about 1000 changes per day.

**Destination**
Azure MS SQL database which I have full control over.

I'm looking for best practice or any ideas on how to achieve this. There seems to be very few articles that I can find with anything helpful.

I'm open to using any tool on Azure including Logic Apps and Azure Functions but want to stay away from using 3rd party tools.

Comment: Perhaps you could use a logic app with a recurrence trigger and countinuously call the API to get new rows and then use a logic app SQL-connector to INSERT the row into the SQL-server.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to achieving this through logic apps, Below is the flow that you can follow.

***Note:*** Make sure you preprocess the data before sending the data to SQL database using appropriate actions based on the type of data that you are receiving.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @SwethaKandikonda. How does the request know if the row is updated, rather than inserted? And how does it detect deletes? Excuse my lack of API Knowledge!